# Check if type is derived from another type

Tags: typewriter

I want to check if the current property type is derived from another type

```
string TypeConverter(Type type)
{
     if(type.??.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Entity)))

}
```

How do I get C# type object of the CodeModel.Type??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to the full C# reflection system in Typewriter templates so you'll have to use a more primitive approach. Try something like this:

```
string TypeConverter(Type type)
{
    if(type.BaseClass?.Name == "Entity")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: that would do but then i have multiple entity types. does typewriter show trace statement in in output tab?? and if not can you add support for it?